# Finding the infimum of a set of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the set $S = \{ \frac {\sqrt3}{2n + 1}: n \in \mathbb N\}$. How do I prove that $inf$ $S = 0$? I've already shown that $0$ is a lower bound of $S$ and $S$ is non-empty so $inf$ $S$ exists by the greatest lower bound property of $\mathbb R$. I'm allowed to use the fact that between any two reals there are infinite rationals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: First observe that $S$ is bounded below by $0$. Now pick any $\epsilon > 0$, can you find an $n$ such that $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2n+1} < \epsilon$?

Comment: The answer is yes, but how can I prove it is so? I understand that there are infinite rationals between 0 and $\epsilon$ but I'm not sure how to prove that some of those rationals must be of the form specified in S.

Comment: @Vizuna Choose $n>\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\epsilon}-\frac{1}{2}$ what can you say about $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2n+1}$?

Comment: By the Archimedean axiom $\exists N$ such that $\epsilon > \frac{3}{N}$, then $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2N+1}<\frac{3}{2N+1}<\frac{3}{N}<\epsilon$

Comment: @Surb I see what you did there. Thanks! But how did you manage to come up with such a seemingly arbitrary number?

Comment: @Qidi I doubt about $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2N+1}<\frac{1}{2N+1}$...

Comment: @Vizuna Let $\epsilon> 0$ be arbitrary. Suppose there exists $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2n+1}<\epsilon$, then ask yourself: "what should $n$ satisfy so that the inequality is true?" and compute...

Comment: @Surb Oops, fixed it, thanks!